# Creating StringVar() class variables

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a GUI using Tkinter and I've to create class `StringVar` atributes depending on a variable called `initial_numbers`. If `initial_numbers` is 5, I've to create 5 `StringVars()` with the name `self.string_var` plus a number so I can identify them.

If:

```
self.initial_numbers = 5
```

I've to create

```
self.string_var0 = StringVar()
self.string_var1 = StringVar()
self.string_var2 = StringVar()
self.string_var3 = StringVar()
self.string_var4 = StringVar()
```

After creating them, I want to add them to a list called `stringList`

What I've tryed this, but of course it's not working.

```
self.initial_numbers = 5
stringList = []
for i in xrange(int(self.initial_numbers)):
    self.string_var+str(i) = StringVar()
    self.string_var+str(i).set("test")
    stringList.append(self.date_string+str(i))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already put them in a list; why create five individual variables ? Put them in the list directly, and use the index to access them.

```
self.string_var = []                        # create empty list
for i in xrange(self.initial_numbers):
    self.string_var.append(StringVar())     # append to list
    self.string_var[i].set("test")          # access var at index i
```